# Scala - method X overrides nothing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I am trying to perform some unit testing over a Spark Streaming application which involves DStreams.

I found it very useful the following suit: **StreamingSuiteBase**. It contains a method named *testOperation* to which you can pass an input, an operation to test and an expected output. It will verify if your expected output matches with the actual output.

The problem I am facing is during the equality verification I am getting indeed the exact same object, but wrapped into different collections:

- expected: List(myObject)
- actual:   Array(myObject)

The testOperation is defined as follows:

```
  def testOperation[U: ClassTag, V: ClassTag](
      input: Seq[Seq[U]],
      operation: DStream[U] => DStream[V],
      expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[V]],
      ordered: Boolean
    ) (implicit equality: Equality[V]): Unit = {
    val numBatches = input.size

    withOutputAndStreamingContext(setupStreams[U, V](input, operation)) {
      (outputStream, ssc) =>

      val output: Seq[Seq[V]] = runStreams[V](
        outputStream, ssc, numBatches, expectedOutput.size)
      verifyOutput[V](output, expectedOutput, ordered)
    }
  }
```

Which doesn't let me use as expected input a `List(Array(myObject))`

So my second option was to modify the method `verifyOutput`. I was planing to override it from my code, just adding a few lines to generate the List(Array(myObject)). Like this (**Updated**):

```
override def verifyOutput[V](output: Seq[Seq[V]],
                             expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[V]],
                             ordered: Boolean)
                             (implicit evidence$1: ClassTag[V], equality: Equality[V]): Unit = {
    super.verifyOutput(output, expectedOutput, ordered)
}

        //These three lines is what I am planning to add
        val sq = expectedOutput(0)
        val ssq = sq(0)
        val newOutput = Seq(Array(ssq))

        logInfo("--------------------------------")
        logInfo("output.size = " + output.size)
        logInfo("output")
        output.foreach(x => logInfo("[" + x.mkString(",") + "]"))
        logInfo("expected output.size = " + expectedOutput.size)
        logInfo("expected output")
        expectedOutput.foreach(x => logInfo("[" + x.mkString(",") + "]"))
        logInfo("--------------------------------")

        // Match the output with the expected output
        assert(output.size === expectedOutput.size, "Number of outputs do not match")
        if (ordered) {
          for (i <- output.indices)
            equalsOrdered(output(i), expectedOutput(i))

        } else {
          for (i <- output.indices)
            equalsUnordered(output(i), expectedOutput(i))
        }

        logInfo("Output verified successfully")
      }
```

The whole StreamingSuiteBase can be found [here](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/src/main/1.3/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/StreamingSuiteBase.scala)

But I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

> method verifyOutput overrides nothing. Note: the super classes of
>   class myClass contain the following, non final members named
>   verifyOutput: def verifyOutput[V](output: Seq[Seq[V]],expectedOutput:
>   Seq[Seq[V]],ordered: Boolean)(implicit evidence$1:
>   scala.reflect.ClassTag[V],implicit equality:
>   org.scalactic.Equality[V]): Unit

This is a simplify version of my test case:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class myClass extends StreamingSuiteBase with FunSuite {

  test("ExtCustProfileHbaseAPI") {

    //Here I would be generating my input and expected output

    val inputData = new myInitialObject()
    val expOutput = new myFinalObject()


    testOperation(inputData, processTest _, expOutput, ordered = false)


  }

  def processTest(input: DStream[myInitialObject]): DStream[(String,myFinalObject)] = {

        //Operation undertes
        val result = operation(input)

        result
    }

    //Here I added the override def verifyOutput[V: ClassTag]...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you extend trait StreamingSuiteBase? Could you show a definition of your test class?

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov I added the definition of the test class

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/src/main/1.3/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/StreamingSuiteBase.scala), the `StreamingSuiteBase` trait has a self type `org.scalatest.Suite` which means you have to extend Suite type class as well (in your case it is [FunSuite](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.FunSuite)) along with it otherwise it won't compile.

You can refer this: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/StreamingSuiteBase

For more information on Scala self types, you can refer: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html

You don't need a `V: ClassTag` the basic IDE generated overridden method I can see is:

```
override def verifyOutput[V](output: Seq[Seq[V]],
                             expectedOutput: Seq[Seq[V]],
                             ordered: Boolean)
                             (implicit evidence$1: ClassTag[V], equality: Equality[V]): Unit = {
    super.verifyOutput(output, expectedOutput, ordered)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I add this (I updated the code with your recommendation), but I  am facing still the same error.

Comment: Updated my answer with an IDE generated default/super override method, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this new feedback, but still with same error.